# VsCode does not indicate the correct version

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Why not specified correct version of java JRE in my vscode ?
Here is my java version.

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

And env path here,

```
$env | grep JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And user setting in vscode,

```
"java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home",
```

When open java project in vscode, next error occurred.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vNO4.jpg)

Hello.Thank you.

Comment: is this a maven project?

Comment: No, it's only test project .